# WordPress - How do you merge two or more loops together?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've read the multiple loops codex on WordPress but I'm still a bit confused on how to do this.

I have to run 3 queries from the default query.

-1 = the most recent post from X category

-2 = all posts from Y category

-3 = all posts except the most recent (because it's pulled in -1) of X category

This is how I currently have my index.php set up:

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category_name' => 'news',
        );
        $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
            ?>

            <?php while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : $news_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
                    $date = Date('m/y');
                    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                    $link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);               
                ?>

                <?php echo '<div class="recent-news-banner" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">'; ?>

                <?php echo '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><div class="' . 'entry-meta' . '"><div class="meta-date">' . $date . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2><div class="meta-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div></div></div></div></div></div>'; ?>

                <?php echo '</div>'; ?>

            <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( "No News Found", 'news' ); ?></p>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif 
    ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'category_name' => 'events',
            );
            $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            echo '<div id="owl-testimonials" class="owl-theme owl-carousel container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">';

            if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
                ?>

                <?php while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) : $events_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                        $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
                        $date = Date('F j, Y');
                        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                        $link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);               
                    ?>

                    <?php echo '<div class="event-item" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">'; ?>

                    <?php echo '<div class="meta-date">' . $date . '</div>'; ?>

                    <?php echo '</div>'; ?>

                    <?php echo '<div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3></div></div>'; ?>

                <?php endwhile;?>

                <?php echo '</div></div></div>'; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e( "No News Found", 'news' ); ?></p>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif 
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

I wrote it out as two wp_queries but the second one won't load on my [page](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/news-and-events/). I haven't attempted the third because of this. First off is wp_query fine for the default loop? Second, how can I rework this so it'll work with more than loop.

Comment: The generated content appears in the source, but it appears that there's a `display:none` style on the `.owl-carousel` class - are you missing some init for that maybe?

Comment: Another issue looking at the source is it seems `#primary` is inside `.recent-news-banner` but I closed that div so no idea what's going on here. I think it's how the loops are written.

Comment: I count 8 divs opened in the second echo in your first loop, but only 7 closes. Actually, is there a reason you're doing an echo at all? You could just inline those divs so you can format and indent them so it's easier to see what's going on...

Comment: Caught that too. I don't know what to do with this post. What I thought was the issue wasn't at all. It's entirely different. Do I leave it or delete this?

Comment: You can accept my answer below if you like.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code, but I don't believe the loops are incorrect. I am able to see the content generated in the second loop in your page source; it appears that Owl Carousel is not being initialized.

**Issue 1**: Nothing is being assigned to `$`, so the `$('#owl-events').owlCarousel(...)` call isn't working (in fact, it doesn't look like anything in `main.js` is working. You'll need to either let jQuery take over `$` or explicitly use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

**Issue 2**: Unclosed `divs`. In the first loop you echo out 9 divs, but close only 8 of them. This is really easy to miss when piling them all on one line. You don't need to `echo` that content, you could just inline them on the page, and intersperse php where needed, and maintain some formatting so you can see what's going on. For example:

```
...
<?php while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : $news_query->the_post(); ?>
...
  <div class="recent-news-banner" style="background: url(<?= $featured_img ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">'; ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="entry-meta">
            <div class="meta-date"><?= $date ?></div>
            <div class="meta-info">
              <div class="meta-title">
                <h2>
                  <a href="<?= get_permalink() ?>"><?= get_the_title() ?></a>
                </h2>
                <div class="meta-excerpt"><?= get_the_excerpt() ?></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- uh oh, not enough closing divs -->
<?php endwhile;?>
...
```

There may be other issues, but these two should give you a start and allow you (and us) to see any thing else that might be awry.